# Convert multiple columns to binary in R

Tags: r, binary

Hi I have a dataset with multiple columns that are populated with either NA or "Y".  I wish to make these values 0 and 1 respectively.

I am fairly new to R, and trying to determine the best way to loop through these variables and recode them.

```
STATE<-c(NA, "WA", "NY", NA, NA)  
x<-c(NA,"Y",NA,NA,"Y")
y<-c(NA,NA,"Y",NA,"Y")
z<-c("Y","Y",NA, NA, NA)
mydata<-data.frame(x,y,z)
```

I have a large dataset, and many of these variables.  However, some of them (such as STATE), I wish to leave alone.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I think is to use the `mutate_each()` function from the package `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

STATE  <- c(NA, "WA", "NY", NA, NA)  
x      <- c(NA, "Y", NA, NA, "Y")
y      <- c(NA, NA, "Y", NA, "Y")
z      <- c("Y", "Y", NA, NA, NA)
mydata <- data.frame(x, y, z, STATE)

mydata <- mutate_each(mydata, funs(ifelse(is.na(.), 0, 1)), -STATE)
```

It will apply the function specified inside `funs()` to each variable. The dot `.` is a representation for the variable. To skip one or more variables just write their names with a `-` before them: `-var1, -var2, ...`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ifelse`:

```
ifelse(is.na(mydata),0,ifelse(mydata=="Y",1,mydata)
```

This replaces elements of mydata to 0 if they are NA, to one if they are "Y" or keep element if they are anything else.

You added the binary tag. R has a binary type: TRUE/FALSE, so if you want binary, you should use

```
 ifelse(is.na(mydata),FALSE,ifelse(mydata=="Y",TRUE,mydata)
```

instead.

Comment: Is there a way to only perform this action for selected variables (see edit)? Also, I think you're right...binary is what I want.  That is, if they resolve to 1 and 0 in arithmetic functions.  Is TRUE + TRUE equal to 2?

Comment: If you want to modify only some columns, you can do something like `mydata[c('x','y')] = ifelse(is.na(mydata[c('x','y')]),0,ifelse(mydata[c('x','y')]=="Y",1,mydata[c('x','y')]))`where contains the column names you wish to keep. And yes TRUE+TRUE = 2

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure the character vectors are not coded as factors:

```
mydata <- data.frame(x,y,z, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Then:

```
mydata[mydata=="Y"] <- 1
mydata[is.na(mydata)] <- 0
mydata
  x y z
  1 0 0 1
  2 1 0 1
  3 0 1 0
  4 0 0 0
  5 1 1 0
```